# No se instala smtplib

Tags: python, cmd

quiero instalar la librería smtplib de Python, pero me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando Python 3 con la versión pip-22.0.4

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe (probablemente) a que la librería de hecho no existe en Pypy.

De cualquier modo, no hace falta instalarla, ya que viene con [la librería estandar de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/). Es decir, que ya viene con Python.